# Jquery, change caret class on click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this html code below with the caret class `fa fa-caret-down`. Now I want that if the user clicks on the caret, the caret-down class shall gets removed and get replaced with the `fa fa-caret-up` class. And the same again, if he klicks on the caret-up class, it shall get back to the caret-down class.

( any other way is also okay ). I've tried this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.fa-caret-down').on('click', function () {
        $(this).removeClass('fa-caret-down').addClass('fa-caret-up');
    });
    $(this).removeClass('fa-caret-up').addClass('fa-caret-down');
});
```

[ This toogle also runs very bad with this code ]

But this only works for the first part. If I'm trying to get back to the caret-down, nothing happens.

Thats my HTML:

---

```
<div id="acc-construct" class="hidden">
    <div class="acc-group">
        <div class="acc-head">
            <a class="acc-toggle collapsed acc-default" data-toggle="collapse"
               data-parent="#acc" href="#collapse-divsInContainer">
                <i data-arrow="" class="pull-right fa fa-caret-down"></i>
            </a>
        </div>
        <div id="collapse-divInContainer" class="acc-body collapse">
            <div class="acc-inner">
                <dl class="dl-horizontal"></dl>
                <div class="separator"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I'm still new in jquery/Js and sorry for my bad english.

Thanks for any help !

Comment: You could check if the button has a caret-down via `.hasClass()`, if it does, remove the `down` and add the `up`. If it doesn't; remove the `up` and add the `down`

Comment: Use `toggleClass()` - it does a lot of work for you http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set another class (`caret-icon`) on the caret element and attach click event to that class:

```
<i class="caret-icon fa fa-caret-down"></i>
```

And use `toggleClass()` method:

```
$(document).on('click', '.caret-icon', function() {
   $(this).toggleClass('fa-caret-up fa-caret-down');
})
```

Comment: `.toggleClass()` is the best way, but you don't really need to add an extra class: the OP's `$('.fa-caret-down').on('click',...` would work fine because the element starts with that class.

Comment: I would suggest the use of an extra class just to group those elements and to prevent the toggling of any future added element with class fa-caret-up / fa-caret-down, that you don't want to have this behaviour

Answer (score 0):

Use 'if - else' condition with 'hasClass' method.

Here is the Jquery

```
      $(document).ready(function () {
            $('.fa-caret-down').on('click', function () {
                if ($(this).hasClass('fa-caret-down')) {
                    $(this).removeClass('fa-caret-down').addClass('fa-caret-up');
                }else{
                    $(this).removeClass('fa-caret-up').addClass('fa-caret-down');
                }
            });
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

`$('.fa-caret-down')` finds the DOM - elements that have the class `fa-caret-down` when the code is executed, in your case after initialization. These elements get a click handler that removes `fa-caret-down` and adds `fa-caret-up`. The elements that have this handler don't change later. So, a second click on one of the elements also removes `fa-caret-down` and adds `fa-caret-up`.

You have to check in the handler if the element currently has class `fa-caret-down` or `fa-caret-up`. If it has class `fa-caret-down` you have to remove `fa-caret-down` and add `fa-caret-up`. If it has class `fa-caret-up` you have to remove `fa-caret-up` and add `fa-caret-down`.

Your current code `$(this).removeClass('fa-caret-up').addClass('fa-caret-down');` does not help because it is executed only one time after initialization.

Comment: I will try that.. give me some minutes.